# How-to suppress  Search icon on Kindle Fire Menu/Actionbar

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

A Search Icon appears in Kindle footer area (which I think is sort of an actionbar).  It always appears on all my activities but I don't have search functionality on every activity.  How do I get rid of it? Please note, I think there is a way since I have seen applications that do not have the search in the footer menu/actionbar on every screen.

Comment: I would like to see code of how to suppress search icon, or have authoritative confirmation from Kindle expert that this cannot be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Kindle Fire [User Guide](http://kindle.s3.amazonaws.com/Kindle_Fire_Users_Guide.pdf) page 8, section Content Bar, the search button helps users search their content library, not search within the current app.

You can partly hide the whole Content Bar by making your app full screen but you can't hide it completely as it replaces the functionality of the home & back buttons on non-kindle android devices. There is no documented way on the [Amazon Developers blog](http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/) on how to remove individual buttons from the soft key bar.