# Kindle Fire Customize Soft Key menu

Tags: menu, key, kindle-fire

Does anyone know how to remove or hide the menu and search buttons from the soft key menu. I'd like to accomplish what is being done in the Pulse app where the search button is hidden or the Kindle Fire help & feedback app where both the search and menu buttons are hidden.

I was curious if they are actually modifying the soft key menu, or making the app fullscreen and placing a graphic of the menu in it's place.

I'm aware of [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956808/how-to-suppress-search-icon-on-kindle-fire-menu-actionbar), which does not adequately answer the question, as there are example of apps with what appears to be modified soft keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can't customize what appears on the soft key toolbar, though you can add/remove items from the overflow menu as well as intercept the back and search buttons.

The overflow menu should *automatically* disappear in API15 and above, but it's not always reliable (on any Android device with an overflow/action menu)

In the Pulse app on my FireHD the toolbar is still visible (with a search button as normal)

More information both on their latest blog post and in the SDK docs referenced
http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2012/10/optimizing-for-soft-key-support-on-kindle-fire-hd.html