# hide menu and search button from kindle fire

Tags: menu, key, kindle-fire

Is there any way to hide menu and search buttons from Kindle Fire? This ([Kindle Fire Customize Soft Key menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807883/kindle-fire-customize-soft-key-menu)) says there's no way to do that, but i hope something has changed since then.

Thanks!

[image: softkeybar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow menu is automatic and controlled by the OS (similar to the Action menu on devices based on the default Android experience). The search icon is fixed and will either take the user to the platform search or you can override it following the instructions [here](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/soft-key-bar.html).

You may also be able to achieve the effect you are looking for with one of the [Full Screen Modes](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/screen-layout.html#StatusSoft) available to Kindle developers.

Do you have a sample of the code that is failing to hide the overflow menu appropriately?

Comment: Thanks for your reply (Actually, i was waiting for you since i had seen a lot your valuable comments on Kindle Fire you left :) ) Based on what you said, it seems that we can hide the overflow menu while we can't hide the search icon. Am I right? At least if we could hide the overflow menu, that is awesome!

Unfortunately, I don't have a sample code now, and am using a phonegap to make a Kindle Fire app. If hiding the overflow menu is possible, could you let me know how to do that with a simple sample code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd have to have a look at PhoneGap - the overflow menu should, according to the documentation, hide if not used. If it's not then it might be something that Amazon and/or PhoneGap need to investigate a little more. What model Kindle are you using (I'll see if I can reproduce the problem if I can make some spare time)

Comment: interestingly with a default PhoneGap 3.0 project on the HD (last years) device the option menu disappears, but with the HDX 7" it doesn't. Will check what the menu behavior is on a Nexus7 tomorrow

Comment: Thanks Offbeatmammal. I'm using PhoneGap 3.1 and on my kindle fire 3rd generation device, the menu button DOES appear.. hm...

Comment: looks like Kindle doesn't behave quite the same as regular Android - seeing same behavior in regular (native) apps as well